# Was the Commodore 128 movable zero page / stack and second block of color RAM actually used?

Tags: commodore-64, memory, commodore-128

The Commodore 128 hardware allowed two things that weren't possible on the C64: Moving the 6502 zero page and 6502 stack to another place in RAM besides pages 0 and 1, and switching the CPU and/or the VIC-IIe to access a second block of VIC-II color RAM. As far as I know, moving the zero page would not affect the fact that addresses $0000 and $0001 were mapped to the CPU's built-in I/O port rather than RAM.

Do you know of any software that actually made use of those features? Second question, were they (or either of them) used by the built-in firmware or the included CP/M system in any way?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

According to COMPUTE!'s, [Mapping the Commodore 128](https://www.cubic.org/~doj/c64/mapping128.pdf), the C128 BASIC firmware makes use of the two color RAM banks to support the "split-screen" graphics modes.

> Normally,the  128  uses  one  block *(insert: of color RAM)* for  character  color  and  the  other  for multicolor bitmapped  mode.  This  is  why  GRAPHIC  4  mode (split  multicolor  bitmapped  and  text)  doesn't  cause  the  conflicts  you  might  otherwise  expect.  That  is,  printing  on  the  textscreen  doesn't  disturb  colors  on  the  multicolor  bitmapped screen,  and  drawing  on  the  multicolor bitmapped  screen doesn't  disturb  the  colors  on  the  text  screen,  even  though  both appear  to  use  the  same  color  RAM.

The same chapter of the book also includes sample code in BASIC 7.0 to demonstrate the use of both blocks of color RAM.

The actual firmware source that implements this is available in the repository [mist64/cbmsrc](https://github.com/mist64/cbmsrc) on Github. From the file BASIC_C128/graphic8.src:

```
sei
lda _6510_data_reg
pha
and #%11111110      ;point cpu at correct nybble bank
sta _6510_data_reg
lda multicolor_2
sta (grapnt),y
pla
sta _6510_data_reg
cli
```

Comment: Until now, I hadn't realized that the C128 replaced the 1Kx4 color SRAM with a 2Kx8 SRAM with only half of the data bits wired.  I wonder how the price of that SRAM compared with a 16Kx4 DRAM?  I think they were pretty similar, and using a 16Kx4 DRAM would have made it possible for the VIC-II chip to support a mixed-res six-color mode by having the VIC-II chip grab four bits from the DRAM with each "shape" byte and use them to select, on a per-pixel-pair basis, whether the two bits of shape data represent two hi-res bits, or a one-of-four color selection.

Comment: DRAM would require refresh circuitry, no? Or is there a guarantee that the entire color ram is accessed frequently enough in all modes? (Standard bitmap Mode?)

Answer (score 2):

LUnix uses hardware stack swapping.

http://lng.sourceforge.net

Comment: This answer's a bit short, but it's a valid answer.

Answer (score 2):

C128 MMU default maps page 0 to bank 0, page 0 and page 1 to bank 0, page 1.
Access to page 0 and 1 therefore ends up in bank0, even when bank1 is switched in.
CPM expects Bank1 for page 0 and 1 therefore during CPM, page0 and 1 are mapped to bank1. You could say it would not matter but in bank0, the MMU maps in the Z80-bootrom when Z80 does a read.
So: page remapping is used as standard (in CPM mode)

Comment: Now that's a surprisingly valid answer.